# NodeJS error with discord bot: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, mathjs

So I'm trying to make a bot that does quick math for me via commands. My prefix is `da$h` and the command is payment. When I try the command `da$h payment 1 + 1` for example, I'm presented with the same error every time. I'm using `mathjs` node btw.

I've tried putting await before send functions and async in front of all the return functions but I get the same exact error.

```
const math = require('mathjs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

exports.run =  (client, message, args, tools) => {

if (!args[0]) return   message.channel.send('Please input a calculation,');

let resp;
try {
    resp = math.evaluate(args.join(' '));
} catch (e) {
    return   message.channel.send('Sorry, please input a valid calculation');
}
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor(0xffffff)
.setTitle('Math Calculation')
.addField('Input', `\`\`\`${args.join(' ')}\`\`\``)
.addField('Output', `\`\`\`js${resp}\`\`\``)

 message.channel.send(embed);

}
```

Here's the error I keep getting:

> node:18876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
>       at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\coding\node_modules\Discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:71:65)
>       at then (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\coding\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:204:21)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:18876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
>   (node:18876) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Did you try to put `.catch()` on all `message.channel.send()`?

Answer (score 1):

I've usually experienced this error before myself so I am here to give you my option. First of all, in the new DiscordJS v13, it seems that a "content" field is required (for more info, please check the documentation on fields [here](https://discord.dev/resources/channel#create-message)), so this can prevent the bot from sending the message only with an embed. To check your DiscordJS version, go to your `package.json` folder that is located in the same folder as your `index.js` and check if the following versions are displayed: `13.0.0` or `13.0.1`. If they are, please consider running the following on the terminal/command prompt:

```
npm uninstall discord.js
```

and then run this command to install a version that allows you to send only the embed, like `v12.5.3`

```
npm install discord.js@12.5.3
```

If that didn't work for you, consider running this code to create a "content" field and send the embed:

```
... (Your rest code)
message.channel.send('Math Calculations', { embed: embed })
```

and then rerun the bot. Im very happy to know if this fixed your problem. Good luck on your bot!

Answer (score 0):

This is an embedded empty field error.

Try to use,

```
console.log(args.join(' '));
console.log(resp);
```

Then you can find what's the null field.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do `message.channel.send({embed: embed})` for embeds with no message

Comment: The `options` parameter of [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) is allowed to be a [RichEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed) or [Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment) object.